Cloud Data Fusion Wrangler - Space in column name
I have an Excel file sitting in GCS. I have no control over how this is created.
I'm loading the source using a GCS plugin and then trying to transform the data using Wrangler. Wrangler then has issues with a space in a column name.
Any directives I write on that column throw runtime errors and the output schema gives me a warning on that column. I tried wrapping the column name in [], '', and "". Any other ideas?

Can you try wrapping it with Backticks? ` its probably same with using  Reserved Keywords wrapping with backticks.
Reference: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical#reserved_keywords
